# Compile Error when using singleton with generics and completionHandler

Tags: swift, generics

I have the following generic type:

```swift
public enum APIResult<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(NetworkError)
    
    public var value: T? {
        if case let .success(value) = self {
            return value
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    public var error: NetworkError? {
        if case let .failure(error) = self {
            return error
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And I have the following call that I make defined inside a singleton:

```swift
public func getGenericData<T>(urlEndPoint:String,completionHandler:@escaping(APIResult<T>)->()) {}
```

I am calling it using the following code:

```swift
APIManager.shared.getGenericData(urlEndPoint: "getuserprofile") { (result:Any) in
            
}
```

but swift refusing it saying:

Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred.

What would be my problem?

Comment: not related to the problem but you could consider using Swifts built in Result type instead of declaring your own one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler what kind of APIResult to expect, like this

```
getGenericData(urlEndPoint: "getuserprofile") { (result:APIResult<String>) in

}
```